# Saved Queries in Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap-query

We have a query that displayed all the members of a certain group like below. But just I can see those user object inside mail group. Also I want to display mail contact object too.

My query :

```
(&(&(|(&(objectCategory=person)(objectSid=*)(!samAccountType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=3))(&(objectCategory=person)(!objectSid=*))(&(objectCategory=group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=14)))(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=group,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=local)))
```

Comment: Remove the `(objectClass=user)` clause from the query filter to have it include contacts too

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  Hi , I have a issue related to the toast notification. please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113466/toastnotification-how-to-change-the-font-color-and-also-how-to-make-the-backgro